# Instead of storing the images directly, can i store only the paths in hbase?

Tags: java, hadoop, hbase

I want to store image & video (separate cf) in my hbase table. Can I store only path of that media file so that I can retrive image/video it instead of converting image/video into byte[]?

I am new at Hadoop/hbase. So a detail example will really help me.

Comment: It is possible to do either. Which one you need depends on your use cases. Consider your image and video sizes and what you want to do with them, how you want to consume them. Not sure what you mean by _clicking_ though.

Comment: I want to store image and process that with opencv. Size is a big issue thats why i am wanting to store paths. Can you give an example please?

Comment: Take a look at http://hbase.apache.org/book.html#hbase_mob